# Add parameter to url. Make url dynamic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a function and i am trying to add the id parameter to the url and dynamically change the url and add the id parameter to it. but using curly braces doesnt reflect the parameter.

```
submitRating(rate, id) {
  this.setState({
    rating: rate,
  });
  console.log(this.state.rating);
  console.log(id);    ------> the console calls the id eg. id = 3499583
  const url = "https://oversight-ws.herokuapp.com/api/politicians/{id}/rating"  ---> that id should be rendered here on {id}
  console.log(url); ---> i want to return this url https://oversight-ws.herokuapp.com/api/politicians/3499583/rating
  return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `es6` so you can use the string interpolation to do that :

```js
const id = 3499583;
const url = `https://oversight-ws.herokuapp.com/api/politicians/${id}/rating`;
console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const id = 1

const url = "https://oversight-ws.herokuapp.com/api/politicians/" + id + "/rating"
```

or

```
const id = 1

const url = `https://oversight-ws.herokuapp.com/api/politicians/${id}/rating`
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ES6` and refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings) you van write it like this

```
const id = 3499583;
const url = `https://oversight-ws.herokuapp.com/api/politicians/${id}/rating`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES2015 template literals feature.

[Template Literals MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
`string text ${expression} string text`

` => back-tick on keyboard

${} => placeholder within template

const url = `https://oversight-ws.herokuapp.com/api/politicians/${id}/rating`
```

===========================================================================

```
submitRating(rate, id) {
  this.setState({
    rating: rate,
  });
  console.log(this.state.rating);
  console.log(id);    ------> the console calls the id eg. id = 3499583
  const url = `https://oversight-ws.herokuapp.com/api/politicians/${id}/rating`  ---> that id should be rendered here on {id}
  console.log(url); ---> i want to return this url https://oversight-ws.herokuapp.com/api/politicians/3499583/rating
  return;
```